# Spark out of memory no matter what i do

Tags: apache-spark, memory, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use spark to filter a large dataframe. As a pandas dataframe it would be somewhere around 70GB in memory.

I am able to load and filter this data using pandas, however really slowly because I have to swap to disk etc.

However when i try doing this using PySpark I run into memory errors from Java.

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Master").getOrCreate()
master = spark.read.csv(master_path, inferSchema=True, schema=schema, header=True)

master_desember = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM master_filter_ready WHERE born_month='12'")
master_desember = master_desember.toPandas()
```

**Edit:** So my question is how do I set memory on a spark session before I create it? Also How can I determine what values to use? At the moment I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading comments bellow my question about needing to set memory before creating the session I did this:

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

builder = SparkSession.builder
builder = builder.config("spark.executor.memory", "2G")
builder = builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "10G")
builder = builder.config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "5G")
spark = builder.appName("Master").getOrCreate()
```

This solved my issue. However, I'm not sure why these values worked as I'm not yet familiar enough with how Spark and PySpark works.

If any one have tips on when to set what values where, please answer bellow! :)